# set dynamic input depends on select option attributes

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I want to set the value of input text depends on select option attributes.
[image]

I need when user select product he can see the price in the price field, I retrieved the value in the option, but I don't know how to set the input based on the product because all of the price input has the same name.

View

```
<?php $form=array('id'=>'myform');?>
    <?php echo form_open('Order/submit',$form);?>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Customer Details</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" name="customer_name" id="customer_name">
                            <?php foreach ($customerdata as $c):
                                echo "<option  value ='$c->c_id'>" . $c->c_name . "</option>";
                            endforeach;
                            ?>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="invoice_number" id="invoice_number" placeholder="Invoice Number"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="branch" id="branch" placeholder="Branch"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" name="payment_term" id="payment_term">
                            <option id-="cash">Cash</option>
                            <option id-="bank">Bank</option>
                            <option id-="other">Other</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
            </div><!--customer panel-Body-->
            <div class="panel-heading">Invoice Details
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">

                <div id="education_fields">

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" id="select_product" name="select_product[]">
                            <?php
                            foreach($order as $row):
                                echo"<option data-price='$row->p_price'  value ='$row->p_id'>".$row->p_name. "</option>";
                            endforeach;
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qty" name="qty[]" value="" placeholder="Quantity">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price[]" value="" placeholder="Price">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" name="total[]" value="" placeholder="Total">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"  onclick="education_fields();"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer"><small>Press <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus gs"></span> to add another product field :)</small>, <small>Press <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus gs"></span> to remove the last product :)</small></div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Checkout</button>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Jquery 1: that used to add generate a new row for product.

```
<script>

var room = 0;
function education_fields() {

    room++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('education_fields');
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+room);
    var rdiv = 'removeclass'+room;
    var medo='<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" id="select_product" name="select_product[]"><?php  foreach($order as $row){ ?><option value ="<?php echo $row->p_id; ?>"><?php echo $row->p_name; ?></option><?php }  ?></select></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qty" name="qty[]" value="" placeholder="Quantity"></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Degree" name="price[]" value="" placeholder="Price"></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"> <input class="form-control" id="total" name="total[]" placeholder="Total"/></select><div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_education_fields('+ room +');"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button></div></div></div></div><div class="clear"></div>';

    divtest.innerHTML = medo;
    objTo.appendChild(divtest);
    $('select').selectpicker();
}
function remove_education_fields(rid) {
    $('.removeclass'+rid).remove();
}
```

Jquery 2: here I'm trying to set the price input based on the product .

```
<script>
$('select').change(function(event) {
    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected");

    var myprice = selected.attr('data-price');
    document.getElementsByName(price[]).value = myprice;
    //some dom edits
});
```

Comment: Check your DOM. Seems like you put same id on some inputs, `ex: id='price'`, you can change it into `class='price'` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE FOR JQUERY2**

```
//You must replace id attribute for input box into class
$('select').change(function(event) {
    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected");

    var myprice = selected.attr('data-price');
    //Then we set value for the input box
    $( this ).parent().parent().next().next().find('.price').val( myprice );
});
```

Comment: Not working, I replaced ID with CLASS and updated The Jquery

Comment: worked ! but its effect on all price inputs with the same value, and the main select on the view is the only select work . the second , 3rd select that generated from JQuray 1 not working

Comment: Could you provide your DOM, especially after other selects generated. You can do it by right-click on the page, then choose `View Page Source`. It helps me to know more.

Comment: First, you need to replace all of the `id` attribute with class. You can see that your `select` tags have same id, this is a mistake. Second, more practice with [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: [updated code here, i made some updated in jquery check it may that use to help ](https://codeshare.io/5ePr0b)

Comment: updated! I removed **IDs** from **SELECTS**, made dynamic **ID** related you can see that in the price input,  please check the latest version of my code, I have TeamViewer if you'd like you to check and edit live.

Comment: No, it doesn't work , look to this jquery (https://codeshare.io/2EoqW4)

Comment: `document.getElementById('price'+optionid).value=myprice;`, this is wrong. Remember, price input has class based on `room`, not `optionid`. Try modify my answer instead, it should works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145760/discussion-between-syam-and-ukasyah).